# Idiom for: "We should attend it even if we have to borrow money."

Tags: phrases, expressions, phrase-requests, expression-choice

I'm translating a script and I should cut this line down by about half it's syllables. I should match to the lip movement of the actors on video, and so that would be about 7 syllables. It doesn't have to match exactly but I couldn't think of a phrase, idiom, or word that I regularly use that can match. Can anyone give me a hand?

"We should attend it even if we have to borrow money."

Comment: First thing coming to my mind is "we cannot **not** go to this," but there's almost certainly something better out there.

Comment: I think this is really Off Topic writing advice. How about *Go we must, though beggared we be*, if you want a somewhat "poetic" phrasing? I make that only 8 syllables.

Comment: Or *We must go, at any cost* (or *...at **all** costs*).

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate the comments, to add detail: Jane is saying this to Jack in school. "It' refers to an expensive training course.

Answer (score 2):

Seven syllables:

> Damn the debt, we should attend.

From John Vernon's April 18 installment on redstate.com entitled *[The Lost Art of Patriotism](http://www.redstate.com/diary/johndvernon1/2015/04/18/lost-art-patriotism/)*:

> Damn the debt, full speed ahead with spending.

---

For different lip movements or contextual nuance:

> - The debt be damned, let's attend.
> - Damn the money, let's attend.
> - Damn the debt, we need to go.
> - The debt be damned, we should go.
> - Damn the money, we should go.
> - The money be damned, let's go.

---

Reversing the order of the clauses multiplies the possibility of a good lip sync.

Comment: Thanks for the options ScotM! Although I do like your alternatives, the students want to attend a bible training class and so I feel it may not be proper. They are debating with each other in a church classroom in front of a preacher, and although they are bickering the argument isn't so vicious. But kudos for the options! =)

Comment: LOL! @MovieScriptGuy, they can soften the expletive to *hang*, or some other equivalent and get similar effect. Far be it from me, a preacher of sorts, to put offensive words into the mouths of people who want to carry a pleasant message.